# Can std::async "reuse" threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

As described in title I'd like to know whether tasks ran with `std::async` can "reuse" idle threads.

For example lets take next code:

```
auto task = []() { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20)); };
int tasksCount = 160;
std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

for (int i = 0; i < tasksCount; ++i)
{
    futures.push_back(std::async(task));
}
```

So we have a lot of tasks (160) runned in parallel which do nothing. When this code is running on windows it generates 161 waiting threads.

Isn't it too much threads for doing nothing? Why waiting threads can't be "reused"?

Comment: The threads are executing sleep.

Comment: You asked for threads so program created one. It does not know you are doing nothing. You know it. You should take care of it. In this case threads are busy sleeping

Comment: `Why waiting threads can't be "reused"` Because you didn't make it so they could be?  Perhaps you want to look into condition variables?

Comment: use my version of `async`, it uses threadpool behind the scenes. https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp

Comment: guys, I think the sleeping here is just for the sake of the question, don't nit-pick on it.

Comment: @manni66 Isn't sleep actually doesn't concume any cpu resources? I thought that sleep allow thread to do other work untill some inner callback called.

Comment: Sleep allows other threads running on the same processor to do more work

Comment: @DavidHaim _just for the sake of the question_ I don't think so

Comment: @manni66 Sleep here really just for example, maybe not very good example. But there can be some I/O operation which shouldn't concume cpu time.

Comment: I/O is also executed. You have a fundamental missconception about threads,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread, roughly, is a CPU state and reserved memory space for a stack, plus an entry in an OS scheduler.  The C++ language also has information about per-thread state (`thread_local`), and helper libraries may also have some state.

These are reasonably expensive.  This information cannot be shared between threads; each thread actually has a different stack, a different set of `thread_local` state, different register values, etc.

Now, when a thread isn't executing, it is just an entry in a table.  No CPU resources (other than those caused by a larger table) are spent on the thread.  So you have a large amount of setup costs, a bunch of threads are started, then they go to sleep.  The scheduler doesn't return to those threads until the time they asked to sleep comes up.

So at the hardware level, they are sharing CPUs.  But at the software level, their state isn't shared, and that is what you are seeing in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

The sharing does happen, but at core level, not thread level. Since your threads are doing virtually no computation, it's likely all 160 threads can share a single CPU core.

Fundamentally, a thread holds a call stack, with the local variables of each function invocation. This stack can't really be shared - the fundamental property of a call stack is that the top function is the one actively executing. In your example, you have 160 `sleep_for` on top of 160 stacks.

Answer (score 1):

The important question is: what observable difference would it make to your program? The standard won't talk to what happens at a lowel system level. It will only talk about observable behaviour. There's no gain there, the only observable difference could be unexpected thread local storage variables mixup.

Consider the complexity:

- sleeping threads don't cost much to the system. Having more idle threads won't hurt much
- busy threads can't be reused. Well, not without cost.
- if you wanted to reuse idle threads, how would you know that the reused thread would not become busy after sleeping.

So, in short, it would offer no visible benefit, could break thread local storage, depending on how it is stated in the spec, and would be a major pain to implement. Only for the sake of reducing the number of threads at a lower level.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sleeping here is just for example.
Task can contain some I/O operations that consume no cpu time but need a lot of real time. So it will be nice if thread do some usefull staff while I/O operation in progress.
Talking about benefit - every thread concuming some resources and useless threads are bother me a bit.

Comment: Well if there is some useful work for the thread to do, you can rewrite the thread to either do the work piecemeal and poll the status of the I/O task, or you might register a signal handler which will interrupt your thread in-thread, reentrantly. But the management effort might soon equal that of just having another thread.